# Clients with Multiple IP Addresses - How?

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip

I have a squid transparent proxy that authenticates client based on IP address (the only way available).

The intended setup is my client would sign up, my php page logs the IP to MySql, and Squid would authenticate based on the Ip in the database.

This method works well under normal scenario but I noticed there is a problem because I keep seeing "access denied" in my Squid log.

I realize some client would sign up using IP A, but have a different IP at the same time. 
For example, one client has an Ip of xxx.255.1.58 in Livezilla but xxx.255.1.30 in my Mysql database. This occurred in a single instance (Less than 2 minutes apart).

How is this possible? I understand some clients might have dynamic IP but is this the explanation?

Edit: I've added a sample Squid Log of an user

Within 149 seconds, the person used 10 Ip addresses to access my server, and obviously got denied...Could this possibly be the case for dynamic IP? I don't believe dynamic IP changes this frequently. From my understanding, IP address changes only if you reset the connection.

```
xxx.255.1.20
xxx.255.1.62
xxx.255.1.75
xxx.255.1.86
xxx.255.1.41
xxx.255.1.48
xxx.255.1.75
xxx.255.1.32
xxx.255.1.92
xxx.255.1.65
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any corporate user is likely sitting behind several proxies, therefore potentially every request will appear from a different source IP address.

Usually for HTTPS requests the proxy system is configured to use the same source address, however for regular HTTP it is a free for all.

Comment: Thanks Steve, Such setup is not common within residential Internet users is it? My target audience is mainly residential users not corporate.

Comment: @Nick Currently not so popular, but expect it to rapidly rise with scarcity of IPv4 addresses.  It could be then simply ISP level NAT rather than proxying which would also affect HTTPS.  It is possible iPad/iPhone users on certain networks might be in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of reasons why a client might have multiple IPs. It depends entirely on how they access the internet (Their ISP).

Comment: HI, my client had 10 different IPs within 149 seconds. Is there an ISP setup out there that gives up new IP on every HTTP request?